# How to use regex like /page/.*/page/ in Nginx location

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

Url example:

```
http://test.com/test/page/4?-test?o?o_html/page/100/page/2/page/3/page/4/page/4/page/2/page/106/page/107/page/2/page/3/page/4/page/108/page/3/page/2/page/3/page/4&-test
```

I want to use nginx location to forbidden it.
But I faild, I have tried different rules in http://nginx.viraptor.info/

`location ~ /page/.*/page/ {
    return 403;
}`

```
location ~* \/page/.*/page/ {
location ~* /page/\.*/page/ {
```

None of them worked...

I found only use /page/ is Worked.

```
location ~* /page/ {
```

But when I add .*/page/ like:

```
location ~* /page/.*/page/ {
```

It's not worked...

Now I use php to judge url like:

```
if (preg_match ("/\/page\/.*\/page\//i", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]))
```

Please tell me how to use regex .* in nginx conf location. I want to use nginx.

Comment: You are trying to match arguments with the page url and the match is done on url this way. Which is `/test/page/4` in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything after the first `?` are URI arguments, they are not part of the URI, as such a location match will never work. If there is a solution that allows you to do this in Nginx, it will be a kludge, you should perform this level of checking in your script like you stated you are already doing.

See: https://serverfault.com/questions/811912/can-nginx-location-blocks-match-a-url-query-string

Comment: Oh my god. How carelessly I am, I actually ignored it is actually a parameter. Thank you for your reply~ I use `if ($query_string ~ "/page/.*/page/") {
    return 404;
}
`to solve this problem.